# How to return a Task<T> in an async method

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, task, async-await

I have this method in my Windows Phone 8 app where I get some data from a url

```
   public async static Task<byte[]> getData(string url)
    {
    HttpClient client = null;
    HttpResponseMessage response = null;
    Stream stream = null;
    byte[] dataBytes = null;
    bool error = false;

    try
    {
        Uri uri = new Uri(url);

        client = new HttpClient();
        response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
        dataBytes = getDataBytes(stream); 

        if (dataBytes == null)
        {
            error = true;
        }
        else if (dataBytes.Length == 0)
        {
            error = true;
        }
    }
    catch (HttpRequestException )
    {
    }

    if (error)
    {
        return getData(url); // this is where the issue is
    }

    return dataBytes;
    }
```

But since the method is an async one, the return type cannot be a Task, like I have done on the line `return getData(url);` since `getData(string)` returns Task. Any ideas on how I can rewrite this to make it work?

Comment: What is `getData(url)`? You're calling same method recursively?

Comment: `return await getData(url);` may work. But overall, you should rewrite your method to use a loop instead of recursively calling it again when an error occurs.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yes I call it recursively when an error occurs.

Comment: @NiiLaryea Bad Idea, Ideally you should have some limit, not to call recursively again and again. This may lead to `StackOverflowException`. btw `await getData(url);` will solve your problem

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Actually, I'm not certain it will result in a stack overflow, since the compiler does some rewriting around the `await` keyword. Still, it's better to write the method with a loop, if only for readability. Your first comment shows that this code is abnormally hard to understand.

Comment: @NiiLaryea I just realized there's an error in your code. `error` is initialized to false. If an exception is thrown when downloading the resource, the whole `if (dataBytes == null)` will be skipped, and `error` will still be false, thus exiting the method without retrying.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I actually do have a recursive count but didn't include in the code to make it simpler. But, yea I think I need to rewrite like KooKiz suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awaiting the result of `getData` may do the trick. Still, I strongly recommand you to rewrite your method with a loop, rather than recursively call the method again. It makes it hard to read, and may lead to unforeseen issues.

```
public async static Task<byte[]> getData(string url)
{
    bool success = false;

    byte[] dataBytes = null;

    while (!success)
    {               
        try
        {
            Uri uri = new Uri(url);

            var client = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client.GetAsync(uri);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            var stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
            dataBytes = getDataBytes(stream); 

            success = dataBytes != null && dataBytes.Length > 0;
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException)
        {
        }
    }

    return dataBytes;
}
```

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I'm not sure, I've edited the answer 3 or 4 times right after posting it. This version should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

you can get around the compile error by adding changing the return to the following :

```
if (error)
{
return await getData(url); // this is where the issue is
}
```

I hope you do realize that this code will keep on looping as long as no data is returned? having many clients like this could easily overload your server.